# servlet 3.0 async-supported with jersey

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous, jersey, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to understand under what circumstances the `async-supported` tag is needed in web.xml for async servlet processing with Jersey. If I'm doing any async work, I typically put it in there. But to illustrate, I have setup a simple sevice

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void myService(@Suspended AsyncResponse response) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {               
            response.resume(someResponseObject);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

In this case, if I don't put `async-supported` in my web.xml, this works fine.

Is this not working asynchronously as I think or are there some specific operations I need to do to before enabling `async-supported` is required?

Answer (score 0):

The `async-supported` option in the web.xml or the equivalent servlet annotation `@WebServlet(... asyncSupported=true)` is used to indicate on the servlet level that potential long running background work is carried out which should be handled in a separate thread from the one that is handling the request. The thread handling the request is not blocked for this background work, the doGet() or doPost() method returns and the thread can be used to handle another request. The task will be put in a queue and will be handled by a thread from a threadpool initiated on application startup.

This has actually nothing to do with the Jersey AsyncResponse which is handled by the Jersey implementation. Your Jersey REST service is not a servlet.